# Extending private inner classes: Is it better to use reflection hacks or copy/paste the base class?

Tags: java, reflection, eclipse-plugin, polymorphism

An open source library has an abstract Java class I am extending called `AbstractDialog`. It has a private inner class `A` and a private member `A a` that it instantiates in the constructor. Unfortunately, I need to customize the behavior implemented in `A`.

Should I use reflection to set the `a` member variable to my own implementation? Or copy the source code for `AbstractDialog` into my project and make `A` and `a` protected?

---

<sub>General answers are best, but in my specific case I want to override the behavior of [`ContentProvider`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.4.2/org.eclipse.ui/workbench/3.106.2/org/eclipse/ui/dialogs/FilteredItemsSelectionDialog.java#FilteredItemsSelectionDialog.ContentProvider) in the abstract class [`FilteredItemsSelectionDialog`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.4.2/org.eclipse.ui/workbench/3.106.2/org/eclipse/ui/dialogs/FilteredItemsSelectionDialog.java#FilteredItemsSelectionDialog) for an Eclipse plugin I am developing.</sub>

Comment: I would suggest using a wrapper around it instead of extending it.

Comment: There's no way that I can see to extend the behavior I want by using a wrapper. The functionality is completely contained inside the private inner class.

Comment: You could subclass `ContentProvider` and set it with `setContentProvider()`. There seems no need for reflection at all?

Comment: @CoronA you're right. I was hoping to avoid re-implementing all of the `ContentProvider` boilerplate, but that would be the cleanest solution. (Also... somehow I read every usage of `contentProvider` in the code and missed that method somehow).

Comment: Out of the two options you've provided, the second one is better.

Comment: If possible, you might also want to ask the library's developers about your situation - maybe there's a better way to do what you want to do, or maybe they'll add one in the next version just for you. (Eclipse code seems to often be *intended* to be extensible, but without actually being extensible, because they didn't Write Three Clients)

Comment: Note that `FilteredItemsSelectionDialog` imports several internal classes, if you copy it your copy will be breaking the Eclipse API Rules of Engagement unless you can remove the dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `A` is private, it was not intended for external use and thus presumably provides no guarantees about working the same way, or even existing in the future. So reflection hacks are out. Copy it, and control the implementation. If it diverges, fine. If you controlled the framework, I would refactor to make A generally usable, but since you don't, you don't have many options.